# How to go back to parent array in a reference?

Tags: php, arrays, reference

```
$a = [ 

  [

    [

    ]


  ],

  [

    [

    ]

  ]

];
```

If I have a reference to an element deep in the array, for example:

```
$ref = &$a[1][1];
```

how can I go back to the parent array, in this case `&$a[1]` ?

I'm assigning the reference by relying on a counter variable that increases or decreases. The problem comes when I decrease, then I need to go back to the parent array :(

I think I got it:

```
      $new_ref = &$a;
      $i = 0;
      while($i < $counter - 1){
        $new_ref = &$new_ref[count($new_ref) - 1];
        $i++;
      }  

      $ref = &$new_ref;
```

but it doesn't seem to work right lol.
I dont know why, the logic is ok. I'm using a new reference to climb up the array until near the last level :/

Comment: Arrays have no knowledge of the parent array that they are in.  If you want to track such relationships, you have to do it yourself, perhaps with a recursive data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One cannot "go back" like this.

The child array does *not* know the of the parent array implicitly, reference or not.

To create such a *cyclic dependency* requires explicitly establishing the cycle - usually where such is done it is with a custom class (e.g. a control has a Parent control and many Children controls) and not an array.

I would try to avoid such a cyclic graph and restructure the design - this is because it feels (and especially without an *actual* use-case) that such an approach is creating uncessary complexity.

Comment: "I recommend avoiding such code" --- anything particularly wrong with it?

Comment: I think its possible with some kind of eval but not sure how to do it

Comment: @thelolcat It is not possible to immediately traverse back as the information is simply .. missing. It is like asking for which variables (not references) contain a particular value. One could *search* the object-graph for the particular array in order to find the parent (just as one could search all the known variables for a particular value), but this should be unnecessary in the program design.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are simple things. We can put many variables inside an array, we can even name the locations that we store this information - but they are not related in an object sense to one another.

The structure that is used in accessing data in arrays is simply there to make it more intuitive to anyone reading the code.

Any element of an array is in fact simply a snippet of information with a specific address. While it may be intuitive to think that as one bit of information is inside an array, which is inside another array - all it really means that has happened is that the information inside one part of the array is more complex and can be accessed more precisely.

Classes and Objects on the other hand... this is where parent/child relationships can and DO occur.

Passing by reference is no different:

```
$ref = &$a[1][1];
```

Simply means - any changes to `$ref` are changes to `$a[1][1]`. Whether it is in a function (which would normally make it outside of scope) or whether it is simply a shorter way to write the variable `$a[1][1]` in the rest of your code.